# Server crashed from traffic spike, now getting database connection error

Tags: database, wordpress, crash, connection

So I posted a new blog on my site and promoted it on my facebook where the traffic spike was far bigger than anticipated, the server went down from the volume of traffic and after it was rebooted I am now getting a database connection error.

I contacted my server host and they told me this:

---

"I was able to get the relevant database details from the wp-config.php file in the home directory for your site and, using those creds I am able to connect to the relevant database without a problem.
To be sure that I was able to connect AND make a query to the database I have also created a simple test script that can be viewed at http://yoursite.com/mysqltest.php

This confirms that the server is responding correctly and that the database itself is able to accept connections and queries.

This leaves us with the likelihood that the issue lies with the scripting/configuration of the wordpress installation which is not something I am going to be able to assist you with.

I suspect that the problem lies with the wp-config.php file but cannot be certain."

---

I can't see how the wp-config would have changed, I haven't touched it in over a month and it's been working fine otherwise. The website was also working fine after I posted that blog, it was only after the server was rebooted that it doesn't. All the other sites on the server remain in perfect working condition. I don't see how a traffic spike could have done this. I'm lost as to what to do next? Please help! :(

D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this database connection test script https://gist.github.com/162913